# Copy Rows Using Python from MySQL Database (Server 1) to another MySQL Database (Server 2)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I am trying to use Python 3 to copy a large number of rows from a MySQL database on a server to a MySQL database on a different server.

```
db_A = mysql.connect(...)
db_B = mysql.connect(...)

# Get the required rows from first MySQL database
sql = 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE last_updated > {0}'.format(last_updated)
cursor = db_A.cursor()
num_of_rows = cursor.execute(sql)
```

Is there an efficient way to use the results above to insert into a second MySQL database whose connection is `db_B`?

Comment: When enabled or compiling is a option look take at [FEDERATED Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) -> *"The FEDERATED storage engine lets you access data from a remote MySQL database without using replication or cluster technology. Querying a local FEDERATED table automatically pulls the data from the remote (federated) tables. No data is stored on the local tables. "* .. then you could simply do .. `INSERT INTO remote_table SELECT * FROM local_table` when all "remote" tables are created.

Comment: .   Looks a bit wierd when you read this comment here  but read the manual then it would/should become more clear..

Comment: I've done this before (only on Oracle) by wrapping the SELECT statement outputs into a series of INSERT statements.  This can be done by constructing your SELECT statement to output the INSERT string(s) required around each output.  Hope this makes sense ...